# How to hide loglevel and time in logrus

Tags: csv, logging, go

I am trying to write the logs in CSV format. I am trying to use [logrus](https://github.com/Sirupsen/logrus) to write the CSV as logs. But I see the log level (info) and the time getting added to the CSV content in logs. Like,

time="2015-11-18T01:27:38-04:00" level=info msg="100,Click,Android"

How can I write only my message using logrus?
Or should I use any other loggers available in golang?

Note: I am a newbie to go

Comment: From your example it looks like only content of `msg` is the actual CSV. What is your expected output? `msg="100,Click,Android"` or simply `100,Click,Android`?

Comment: Yes ```msg``` itself is a csv. So I simply need ```100,Click,Android```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> I am trying to use logrus to write the CSV as logs. But I see the log level (info) and the time getting added to the CSV content in logs.

It looks like you definitely shouldn't be using logrus, as the main reason it exists is creating *structured* logs, i.e. key-value style. Not sure why don't you simply do

```
fmt.Println("100,Click,Android")
```

or

```
fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "100,Click,Android")
```

if you want it to be written into the standard error (default for loggers).

If for any reason you need a *logger,* you can pretty much do the same thing with the [standard logger](https://golang.org/pkg/log/) by disabling flags:

```
log.SetFlags(0)
log.Println("100,Click,Android")

// Output:
// 100,Click,Android
```

However, if you're creating a CSV output yourself (i.e. you have spearate fields rather than full CSV lines already), use [csv package](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/) from the standard library:

```
w := csv.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
w.Write([]string{"100", "Click", "Android"})
w.Flush()

// Output:
// 100,Click,Android
```

Unless you just *want* to use logrus, then follow the concept of the package and stick with structured output:

```
logrus.WithFields(logrus.Fields{
    "id": "100",
    "event": "Click",
    "os": "Android",
}).Info("Hooray, we have some users!")

// Output:
// time="2015-11-19T15:20:32+01:00" level=info msg="Hooray, we have some users!" event=Click id=100 os=Android
```

Comment: That really helps. The reason I tried to use logger, is the file handling and daily rolling will be taken care by logger right? Is there any logger which take care of file rolling and also just prints the message?

Comment: Neither standard logger nor logrus can roll the log files. You can use [lumberjack](https://github.com/natefinch/lumberjack) package (which works with any `io.WriteCloser`) for this functionality, although I usually do this from outside, via process supervisors, like supervisord.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the timestamp like this:

```golang
var logger = logrus.New()
logger.Formatter.(*logrus.TextFormatter).DisableTimestamp = true
logger.Info("no timestamp is shown")
```